# Spring Boot 1.5.9.RELEASE - Eureka is using hostname instead of ipaddress inspite of forcing it in application.yml

Tags: netflix-eureka

I have a stand alone spring boot application (version - 1.5.9.RELEASE) which is a client registers with Eureka server.
The applicaiton.yml file which is required by spring boot application looks like below

```
spring:
  application:
    admin:
      jmx-name: hello-server

server:
  port: 8070
  address: 10.12.134.54

eureka:
  client:
    register-with-eureka: true
    fetch-registry: true
    availability-zones:
      local: http://10.12.134.54:8070/eureka/
  instance:
    prefer-ip-address: true
    hostname: localhost
```

But when I start the application, it fails to register with Eureka server because it is using hostname:port instead of ipaddress:port.

Can anyone suggest me how to get rid off this problem?

Here is the error log

```
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:121) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:144) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:134) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:610) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:445) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:835) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:118) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
    at com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.ApacheHttpClient4Handler.handle(ApacheHttpClient4Handler.java:173) ~[jersey-apache-client4-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    ... 72 common frames omitted

2017-12-21 18:23:05.031  WARN 15652 --- [           main] c.n.d.s.t.d.RetryableEurekaHttpClient    : Request execution failed with message: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
2017-12-21 18:23:05.033 ERROR 15652 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_UNKNOWN/MOB80737.hq.k.grp:8070 - was unable to refresh its cache! status = Cannot execute request on any known server

com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: Cannot execute request on any known server
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:111) ~[eureka-client-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134) ~[eureka-client-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is my Eureka client config:

```
eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: ${DISCOVERY_URL:http://discovery-service:8761}/eureka/
    registry-fetch-interval-seconds: 6
    instance-info-replication-interval-seconds: 6
    register-with-eureka: true
    fetch-registry: true
    heartbeat-executor-thread-pool-size: 5
    eureka-service-url-poll-interval-seconds: 10
  instance:
    leaseRenewalIntervalInSeconds: 10
    leaseExpirationDurationInSeconds: 20
    prefer-ip-address: true
```

Hope this helps